# Content Type Layout for Users

Tags: entities, nodes

I have a content type with fields that I want to customize for my clients to look more professional that it does in the current layout. Is this possible?

Comment: Do you mean you want to change the CSS?

Comment: i've done it that way. i was just wondering if there was a different way to do the layout.

Comment: It is also possible to change the admin theme, but apart from that and CSS modification there really is no standard way to change it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [Display Suite](https://www.drupal.org/project/ds) to create custom layouts of your forms and content displays.

> Display Suite allows you to take full control over how your content is displayed using a drag and drop interface. Arrange your nodes, views, comments, user data etc. the way you want without having to work your way through dozens of template files. A predefined list of layouts (D7 only) is available for even more drag and drop fun!

A combination of Display Suite and css will allow you to really tweak the standard layout of your theme.

Otherwise [Panels](https://www.drupal.org/project/panels) is another module that allows you to customize the layout, among many other features.